# Button in UITableViewCell — identify cell when button is pressed in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Sorry for the long title!

The issue here is pretty simple and it's something that I don't have a workaround for — well unless I write redundant code and GUI stuff.

Consider two UITableViewCells that have the same cell identifier — basically they look the same but have different kinds of data. Consider the Apple Store app. In the featured section — you have 'Best Games' and 'Best Apps' tableview cells. They both have a 'See All' option. This is pretty similar to what I have.

**I wish to identify from which cell was this 'See All' button pressed.** (Considering, I have a single segue going to another view controller when either of the 'See All' buttons are pressed.)

Note: I don't want to make another UITableViewCell. I can but I don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(void)yourButtonPressed:(id)sender
{    

    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
    NSLog(@"%i",hitIndex.row);

}
```

This is the best way to get " the button's row "

Comment: Oh well, aren't you awesome. Thanks!